# Using CSS only in FXML

Tags: java, css, fxml

I am mainly a web developer learning Java and currently, I am working on **FXML**.

There are a lot of possibilities in terms of positioning and styling like the panes, but since I am familiar with **CSS** I was wondering if it is a bad practice to do everything in **CSS** instead of using panes like you would in **HTML**.

Are there any downsides to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Scenebuilder](https://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/). It will autogenerate some css for you to play around with.

In general, no, it's not bad practise to use css as freely as you would in HTML. 
However, you do not have the flexibility of using `margin-left:calc(50% - div-width/2);` and similar tricks.

Comment: Thanks that's helpful!